# Understanding PyTorch training batches

Tags: pytorch

Reading https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/pytorch-how-to-generate-data-parallel & https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-does-enumerate-trainloader-0-work/14410 I'm trying to understand how training epochs behave in PyTorch.

Take this outer and inner loop :

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i1,i2 in enumerate(training_loader):
```

Is this a correct interpretation : ?

For each invocation of the outer loop/epoch the entire training set, in above example `training_loader` is iterated per batch. This means the model does not process one instance per training cycle. Per training cycle ( `for epoch in range(num_epochs):` ) the entire training set is processed in chunks/batches where the batch size is determined when creating `training_loader`

Comment: yes! you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) returns an iterable that iterates over the dataset.

Therefore, the following -

```py
training_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(*args)
for i1,i2 in enumerate(training_loader):

  #process
```

runs one over the dataset completely in batches.